# How to add popups to MapImageLayer (JavaScript API 4.0 esri)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have to create a web map application with webservices (WMS or WFS).

I use the API for JavaScript of ESRI (4.0) and MapImageLayers for my data.
But I didn't find how to add popups (or "popupTemplate"= to a MapImageLayer.

I use this sample for my code (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers-mapimagelayer-sublayers)

Comment: MapImageLayers is for dynamic ArcGIS services, not for WMS or WFS services. Are you using ArcGIS Server?

Comment: Hi Bjorn Svensson, yes I am using ArcGIS Server and the webservices that I am using are created with ArcGIS Server Manager and ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 4):

You can use identifyTask to configure the popupTemplate for each sublayer of your MapImageLayer.  See the following sample:  [IdentifyTask JSAPI 4.0](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=tasks-identify)

Comment: Thank you. I tried with the sample changing TileLayer in MapImageLayer with my own web service but it didn't work. I have this error :  'code'TypeError: b is null
Trace de la pile :
d<._parsedUrlGetter@http://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/tasks/IdentifyTask.js:4:286
.cache["esri/core/accessoireSupport/Properties"]/</a.prototype.get@https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/:234:320
.cache["esri/core/accessoireSupport/Property"]/</a.prototype.getDescriptor/<
...
g() 4.0:160
e/d<() 4.0:160
.cache["dojo/_base/array"]/</d.filter() 4.0:105
e()'code' .I need to add the "PopupTemplate" on the require ?

Answer (score 0):

so far, no way to do it. 
MapImagerLayer, popupTemplate would not work, ESRI have NOT yet fix this bug,

all I get is empty

```
identifyTask
                       .execute(params)
                       .then(function(response) {


                         var results = response.results;

                         console.log('identify-results: ', results)


                         return results.map(function(result) {
                                                                var feature = result.feature;
                                                                var layerName = result.layerName;

                                                                feature.attributes.layerName = layerName;



                                                                  feature.popupTemplate = {
                                                                    // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
                                                                    title: layerName,
                                                                    content: "{*}",
                                                                    outFields: ["*"]
                                                                  };

                                                                return feature;
                         });
                       })
                       .then(showPopup); // Send the array of features to showPopup()
```